# TSQL - Bulk Insert

Tags: t-sql

```
BULK
    INSERT Table1
    FROM 'C:\\Table1.txt' --location with filename
    WITH
    .
    .
    .
```

The `Table1.txt` is on a Windows Server. How should I write the `WITH-Statement` (Connection String)?

Comment: Please share what you have tried and what is the hurdle that you faced.

Comment: Use the code tags to put code in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
BULK INSERT 
Table1
FROM 
'\\fullpath\Table1.txt' 
WITH 
(FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

Please Note: SQL Server NT service should have access to the specified address, otherwise you will get the following error:

> Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM '\\SERVER\\FOLDER\\FOLDER\\FileName.txt'
```

That's it.

Sorry.THX.